# Freezing my machines IP only for the containers and internal communications

Tags: docker, macos, static-ip-address

We have a system of numerous microservices, which when setup in local, refers to certain services in my local using their IP(of course resolved via Consul).

It becomes a problem when I connect my laptop from different networks, when the IP of my machine changes. Is there a way in which I can freeze the IP of my machine only for the communications from the containers and the services within my machine?

**PS:**

- Of course, loop-back address won't work, as the loop-back address from container will refer to the container itself and not the host machine.
- I can't run with `network=host`, as there will be many services in different containers running in same port.
- I'm using Mac, but looking for generic solution, which would also work in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Your containers shouldn't ever need to know the ip address of your host. For Docker on MacOS, you can use the hostname `host.docker.internal` to refer to the host, and this will work regardless of how your host's primary address changes.

While in the past this wasn't possible on Linux, you can now set up the equivalent alias by mapping that hostname to the magic address `host-gateway`:

```
docker run --add-host host.docker.internal:host-gateway ...
```

That will give you consistent behavior for your configurations under both Mac and Linux.